# Scrolling acting weird with javascript on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

So here is the code I use to scroll (I hope it's not too bad, I only have about 4 days of experience working with this)

```js
const ScrollDelay = 130;

var LastScrollTime = Date.now();
var NewScrollTime = Date.now();
var IsScrolling = false;
var CurrentPage;

function GotoPage(PageNumber) {
    PageNumber = Math.min(Math.max(PageNumber, 1), 5);
    
    if (CurrentPage == PageNumber) {
        return false;
    }
    
    document.getElementById("Page"+PageNumber).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", inline: "center"})
}

function ScrollStart(Wheel) {
    NewScrollTime = Date.now();
    
    if (!Wheel) {
        return false;
    }
    
    Wheel.preventDefault(Wheel);
    Wheel.stopPropagation(Wheel);
    
    if ((NewScrollTime - LastScrollTime) < ScrollDelay || IsScrolling == true) {
        return false;
    }
    
    IsScrolling = true;
    
    if (Wheel.deltaY < 0) {
        GotoPage(CurrentPage - 1);
    } else {
        GotoPage(CurrentPage + 1);
    }
    
    LastScrollTime = Date.now();
    return false;
}

function ScrollEnd() {
    CurrentPage = Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(window.scrollY / innerHeight) + 1, 1), 5);
}

window.onload = function() {
    CurrentPage = Math.round(window.scrollY / window.innerHeight) + 1;
}

window.addEventListener("wheel", ScrollStart, {passive: false});

document.onscrollend = (event) => {
    ScrollEnd();
    IsScrolling = false;
};
```

```css
* {
    font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}



:root::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------Pages------------------------------------------------------ */

.PageContainer {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.Page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#Page1 {
    background-color: darkred;
}

#Page2 {
    background-color: green;
}

#Page3 {
    background-color: purple;
}

#Page4 {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

#Page5 {
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="Main.js"></script>
        <div class="PageContainer">
            <div class="Page" id="Page1"></div>
            <div class="Page" id="Page2"></div>
            <div class="Page" id="Page3"></div>
            <div class="Page" id="Page4"></div>
            <div class="Page" id="Page5"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's supposed to smoothly scroll between the multi-colored pages, however it doesn't work as intended on firefox.

It works normally if you only move 1 notch on the scroll wheel, however doing more than one causes it to stutter and stop.

[This is how it should work (Shown on google chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCWTv.gif)

[This is how it works on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Zm0.gif)

[Edit: Codepen aswell](https://codepen.io/Rax-Rax/pen/qBQLxgd)

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` don't take arguments.

Comment: Can you add the HTML to the snippet so it won't get an error when it tries to scroll to the IDs?

Comment: I created a codepen with it. I read somewhere that on firefox it does (or used to) so I just tried it to make sure.

Comment: You open the snippet editor and put the HTML in the top-left box. It's similar to jsfiddle.

Comment: It doesn't do anything with empty DIVs, there's nothing to scroll to.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's related to the Date code.

Comment: The whole point of Stack Snippet is so you don't have to make a codepen.

Comment: I fixed the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly how your code works it but I heard there's a lot of issues and features that are not supported correctly on firefox for everything related to web pages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).